# How to get just one table via Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

There are three tables in my system:

1. Students
2. Articles
3. categories

A student can write many articles and an article belongs to just one student. And an article can have only one category.

**Article Model**

```
class Articles extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','title', 'body', 'students_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $table = 'articles';

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Students');
    }

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories');
    }
}
```

I have created the above code, because I needed to get an articles list with who written by that article with the category name.

For that I used `$article_list = Articles::get();` in the controller, and it works perfectly.

Then again I needed to get article list (this time I don't need the student name and category names; the output of the article table is more than enough).

But if I use `$article_list = Articles::get();` it outputs the article table joining with the category and students table also.

Is there a way to get just the article table using **Eloquent**?

Comment: You can use query builder for this

Comment: What do you mean by *it outputs article table joining with category and students*? ARe you sure the student and category data actually *id* in the result you get or are these just relation objects on the Eloquent Model?

Comment: @lesssugar  Yes. I get the same result when using `$articles = Articles::with('students')->with('categories')->get();` and `$articles = Articles::get();`. I have confused because of it. I mean after foaeach I can access the category name using `{{ $article['categories']['name'] }}`. SO I know that they has been joined....

Comment: You are able to do that because the Relations are passed on with the Eloquent Model. If you don't want overhead data, use [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#selects) instead to target a specific table only. But, honestly, performance-wise the difference will be negligible.

Comment: what do you get after this much of code :: $articles = Articles::with('students')->get();

Answer (score 1):

Relations within Eloquent are eager loaded so you are safe and it's no harm that categories are also being loaded. Quoted from the docs:

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship
>   data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not
>   actually loaded until you first access the property.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson You're fine with the performance. The data is not actually loaded ultil you access a property first. That's a benefit of eager loading.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson The docs I linked in my answer explain performance considerations well.  If you're going to need the properties, eager loading is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
class Articles extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','title', 'body', 'students_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $table = 'articles';

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Students');
    }

    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Categories');
    }
}

class Student extends Model
{
    public function articles(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Articles');
    }
}
```

you can try **Has Many Through relationship** type

official link: [read more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Answer (score 0):

@jjj's answer is the right one, but to explain in a bit more detail:

```
$articles = Articles::get();
```

will load the only articles.  You can check it like this in your controller:

```
public function articles() {
    $articles = Articles::get();
    return $articles;
}
```

But `$articles` is a collection of models, and each model is "aware" of it's relationships.  So if you try to access one of those relationships, Laravel will silently load it for you.  So if you pass the same `$articles` above to your view (currently without categories), and then in your view do something like:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    {{ $article->categories->name }}
@endforeach
```

it will work, because Laravel is doing the SQL to find each article's category and then name.  As @jjj explains, this is called Lazy loading and is described in the docs.

Incidentally lazy loading like this is usually inefficient, and it would be better to eager load, like you show in one of your comments above.  [It is described well in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).